# Increment DateTime in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the .net driver with C# to connect to mongodb. With mongodb it is possible to [increment](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) values directly in database:

```
Builders<MyObject>.Update.Inc(x => x.TotalCount, 10)
```

Is this also possible with dates?

```
Builders<MyObject>.Update.Inc(x => x.ValidUntil, new TimeSpan(1,0,0)) // add 1 hour
```

Obviously this does not build because the type of the field (`DateTime`) has to match the type of the value (`TimeSpan`) that is added ([see docs](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateDefinitionBuilder_1_Inc__1_1.htm)).

Is there a different way than getting first the date from database, modify it (add 1 hour) and then update it?

Comment: why not just build a filter and update a single property in that document?

Comment: Definitely possible but this way I would loose the benefit of [atomic transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like to me that this feature has not been implemented in mongo yet.

[SERVER-3174](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3174)

Seems like the only way to do this for now is to physically retrieve your document first and then add whatever time you need to and then update.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Other alternative could be to store dates as number (`DateTime.Ticks`). This way increment would be possible.

Comment: @Mathias thats a nice work around!  I'm unsure how I feel about storing ticks inside my database but its definitely a solution.

Comment: This won't be easy to debug (manually check database) also you would loose certain [Date Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)

Comment: Beware that retrieving the document, changing it and updating the date is not safe in case of strong concurrency. Two or more users might retrieve simoultaneously the same document and update it. The last update would overwrite all the others in this case.